# I have to use the expressions that i have stored in lists, but since they are in lists they come with "[expression]"

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy, sympy

Following is the code I'm using to form the expressions that I require and I have stored them in a list. But now I need to solve those equations by iterations, but I'm unable to use those expressions since they are in lists they come as "[expression]". I will be solving the equations by `expression.subs()` method.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols
x,y,z= symbols('x y z')
a= np.array([-6,-2,1])
b= np.array([-2,7,2])
c= np.array([1,2,-5])
d= np.array([-11, -5, 1])

expr= []
def myfun (a,b,c,d):
    var1= a*x+b*y+c*z+d
    expr.append([var1])

for i in range(len(a)):
    myfun(a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i])
```

Comment: Where's the `sympy` tag?  Show the results, or better yet, some intermediate test values.  I don't recommend mixing `numpy` and `sympy`, at least not a the beginning.  `sympy.lambdify` is the best tool for converting a `sympy` expression into a `numpy` compatible function.

Comment: @hpaulj , I added the sympy tag. If sympy, numpy mixing is not recommended what other way can i store the expressions? As for the results or test values: [-6*x - 2*y + z - 11] is the first expr. that I get. Now to use it as an expresssion, Eq(sympify(expression)), the error i get here is sympify error due to '[]'. To solve it, I will define a new function, use solve(expression.subs(x,var).subs(y,var)) and a for loop for iterations, here I get the same error or syntax error since I cannot go past it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the brackets from the append. And for this use, lists are just as good, if not better than arrays.  You aren't doing array calculations.  They are just a source for numbers.

```
In [12]: a= [-6,-2,1]
    ...: b= [-2,7,2]
    ...: c= [1,2,-5]
    ...: d= [-11, -5, 1]
    ...: 
    ...: expr= []
    ...: def myfun (a,b,c,d):
    ...:     var1= a*x+b*y+c*z+d
    ...:     expr.append(var1)
    ...: 

In [13]: for i in range(len(a)):
    ...:     myfun(a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i])
    ...: 

In [14]: expr
Out[14]: [-6⋅x - 2⋅y + z - 11, -2⋅x + 7⋅y + 2⋅z - 5, x + 2⋅y - 5⋅z + 1]
```